# Sysprep Windows 10 LTSC 2021

Tags: sysprep

We are building system controlled by computer running windows 10 ltsc 2021. It is kind of a kiosk system. There is an account, lets call it user1 with local admin rights that will autologon with no password. It also requires quite a few user account customizations.
In the previous version of windows 10 ltsc, i used a baseline windows installation, created the account to be used in kiosk mode and performed all customizations. I used sysprep with unattended file that had CopyProfile set to TRUE, then boot WinPE and use dism to capture image for distribution to new systems.

It worked well until the file associations were reset after imaging, I could work around this issue by deleting certain registry elements before running sysprep (it could be also done offline on captured image).

Then we started building systems based on win 10 ltsc 2021. Immediately started to have different issue. After applying image, all items in Windows security area were not clickable. I could not click for example on Virus and threat protection to setup some virus scans. Recreating user account would fix that (have to create secondary account, delete user1 and create new user1). However the recreated user account would not have all customizations we need.

I started experimenting with CopyProfile set to false. I go to audit mode right before creating user in original windows installation. I install updates, some extra apps we need and also make some non user account specific customizations. The idea is to create final kiosk user account by unattended file passed to sysprep. And here is where I have number of challenges. I create user account user1 in oobeSystem pass. I setup autologon. So far this will work. On first boot it will autologon and go thru the whole first user creation experience. What I need it to do is to have customized user account settings.
Is there a way to provide that via some unattended process? I also need to run one time powershell script on first boot, that performs additional system setups and customizations. Quick test to create FirstLogonCommand in oobeSystem with that should create new folder and simple text file shows that it fails to run. Maybe it runs the command before the user account/session is fully functional, I do not know. The goal is to be able to run specialized powershell script once in context of the user1 account.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently a bug with sysprep and Windows 10 LTSC 2021.
After running sysprep, Windows security breaks for all existing users at the time sysprep was run. It works correctly for new users, including the one created on the OOEB account screen.  Only the UI becomes inaccessible for existing users, while features seem to work correctly.

To fix it, you can run the following command in PowerShell as admin:

> Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage
> -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}

It might show some errors, but it will work. This resets the security app which will fix the UI not showing.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to stop this from happening in the first place.